# What are the tradeoffs in Kruskal's algorithm between performing a sort versus using a Priority Queue?

Tags: algorithm

I'm learning Kruskal's algorithm and I came across a couple of different implementations and was wondering what the tradeoffs might be between them. The two implementations are as follows:

Implementation One
- put all edges in the graph into a priority queue PQ
- remove smallest edge e from PQ
  - if e connects 2 previously unconnected graph components (tested using a Union Find data structure) then add it to the MST
- repeat until the number of edges in the MST equals total number of vertices in graph - 1

Implementation Two
- perform merge sort or quick sort on all the edges in the graph
- remove smallest edge from sorted edge array
then do same as above algorithm

So the only real difference is whether to use a priority queue or perform an up-front sort in O(eloge) time.

What are the trade-offs here? Both implementations seem to have the same runtime to me - O(ElogV). I say logV and not logE because the maximum number of edges in a connected undirected graph is O(V^2) and logV^2 = 2logV and so removing constant factors can be reduced to O(logV).

Answer (score 2):

Both variants have the same asymptotic complexity. The implementation with a priority queue may perform slightly better if there are a lot of edges since actually sorting them all by weight may not be necessary. One needs only the smallest edges until a spanning tree is found. The exact order of the remaining edges is irrelevant.

However, if this results in savings at all depends a lot on the input data. For example, if the edge with highest weight is part of the minimal spanning tree, all edges must be considered. In practice I would not expect much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Henry's answer, in practice the performance of the sorting approach would also depend on what particular variant of which sorting algorithm was used.  E.g. quicksort can be O(n^2) unless an expensive median-finding algorithm is used (which it generally isn't -- and this *usually* doesn't cause problems).

Mergesort is worst-case O(n log n).  Heapsort is too, but its memory accesses are very dispersed, so it tends to benefit much less from caching and RAM burst modes than basically all other sorting algorithms -- which on small-to-medium-size inputs, or nearly-sorted inputs, can make it even slower than fast O(n^2) sorts like insertion sort.  About the most I could say with any confidence is that the PQ approach should beat a heapsort-based sorting approach, since it does a strict subset of the latter's work.